# Extracting data between 2 tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a js newbie. I'm trying to get a table from a really old and outdated webpage that is continually updated (locally) and add it to a different page.

I need to extract table 1 from the following example. Bonus points if you can explain how your solution works.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div> This is table 1 </div>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <a>
         </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div> This is table 2 </div>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <a>
         </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? How are you trying to represent this table within your script? An array? An object?

Comment: There are many ways to solve the issue. Please restrict your question to a specific problem related to code you have written rather than a very general "how do I get a table". In this case you could use `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]` to get the first table, then use *previousSibling* to get the previous siblings until a DIV is found, then get its *textContent*. But there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would give the target element a unique ID, and target it with [**document.getElementById('[target]')**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```js
var element_1 = document.getElementById('one');
console.log(element_1);
```

```html
<div id="one">This is table 1</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="two">This is table 2</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't have access to a unique ID in the HTML, but **do** have an applicable class, you can use [**document.getElementsByClassName('[target]')**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which returns a collection of all elements with the desired class name:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
console.log(elements[0]);
console.log(elements[1]);
```

```html
<div class="target">This is table 1</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="target">This is table 2</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't have access to **either** a unique ID or but have access to **[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)**, it's quite simple to tranverse the DOM with [**.find('div')**](https://api.jquery.com/find/), which returns an array of all the `<div>` nodes. From there you can simply specify the desired index:

```js
var element_1 = $(document).find('div')[0];
var element_2 = $(document).find('div')[1];
console.log(element_1);
console.log(element_2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is table 1</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>This is table 2</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, with raw JavaScript, it is possibly to target elements with [**.childNodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) (made easier with [**.firstElementChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)). You still need to work from a 'unique' point, and in this case, you'll want to work from `body`, or even `document` itself.

Note that in this example, `childNodes[5]` pertains to the second `<div>`, as each 'node' is prefaced by a descriptor of that node. As such, `childNodes[1]` references the first `<div>`, `childNodes[3]` references the `<table>`, and `childNodes[5]` references the second `<div>`.

```js
var element_1 = document.body.firstElementChild;
var element_2 = document.body.childNodes[5];
console.log(element_1);
console.log(element_2);
```

```html
<div>This is table 1</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>This is table 2</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter way is using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). 
DOMParser.parseFromString will parse your html code into DOMDocument object. DOMDocument object has body object. And in turn body has children. Your table1 is the 2nd child in that list .

```
let source = "..." //your html text above
// method 1: use DOMParser
let dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(source, 'text/html')
let table1 = dom.body.children[1]
```

Try this https://codepen.io/minht/pen/EXbgXY?editors=0010#0

Comment: What does this do? How does this answer the question? Don't just blurt out code without explanation!

Comment: You should put that in your answer and not as a comment on your answer.