# Want to change the text (huge amount text) with only a button but in other way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to change a huge amount of text with a single button click but that button click not hrefing to another page i mean not another html file. just simply change the text by click and the text has to change just dynamically without any page loading. i learn a way to change the text but its only a short text which cant be formatted like with p or h1.2.3 tags. I also want to form the changed text. any possibility for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **contents** of the text with JavaScript's **[HTMLElement.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**.
You can change the **style** of the text with JavaScript's **[HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**.

In the following example, I create a function to change the colour and text in a `<div>` by targeting it based on its ID, `text-to-change`. I then call this function on button click:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('text-to-change').innerHTML = 'Text changed!';
  document.getElementById('text-to-change').style.color = 'blue';
}
```

```html
<div id="text-to-change">Text to change</div>
<button onclick="change()">Click to change</button>
```

This example only uses a few words, but will work for **any** amount of text, no matter how large. Just make sure you target the desired element(s).

If you have your text stored in a different file, this can be extended to use AJAX to retrieve the data, and insert the text based on what is retrieved. For this example, I'm going to call a JSON endpoint:

```js
function change() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var retrieved_content = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0].body;
      document.getElementById('text-to-change').innerHTML = retrieved_content;
      document.getElementById('text-to-change').style.color = 'blue';
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="text-to-change">Text to change</div>
<button onclick="change()">Click to change</button>
```

Simply use your target URL in place of `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`. Note that you'll need to modify `retrieved_content` based on the structure of your data on the page you are calling with AJAX, but that `this.responseText` will always represent **everything** that is returned.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: oh thanks :D i learnt this way also but what if i want to use br tag-s etc? or p tags or h1-2-3 tags?

Comment: Not a problem! You can assign an ID to **any** tag. You would use the syntax `<p id="text-to-change>Text</p>` for example. IDs are by far the most easy way to target an element with JavaScript, but there's actually a whole host of other ways. Check out this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771852/2341603) I gave yesterday showcasing some of the other ways :)

Comment: Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)